# js blur validation form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to validate the value of an input, but using this code I don't get the message (the input box becomes still red):

```
document.forms.richiediAPE.your-email.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("Heyy");
    }
});

<!-- html -->
<form name="richiediAPE" action="mail.php">
    <p>
        <label>Name & Surname</label>
        <input class="name&surname" type="text" value="" name="your-name" maxlength="3" required/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input class="email" type="email" value="" name="your-email" required/>
    </p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Request">
</form>
```

Comment: Please post some of your html so we can see the layout of your form.

Answer (score 1):

To get a form in Javascript is with another way:

```
document.forms['form_name']
document.forms['form_name']['form_element_name']
```

Using:

```
document.forms['richiediAPE']['your-email'].addEventListener('blur',function(e){
     /* Yourself actions. */
     alert(document.forms['richiediAPE']['your-email'].value);
     /* This alerts the value of the text input. */
);
```

But you have to know that in document.forms you get a form and a element by its name (name tag, name=""), sure?

Comment: When I click the submit buttom, I get the message "fill this field". Now, with the .addEventListener, i get my CustomValidity. But I want get the messagge also when i change the focus, without having to click submit

Comment: You just need add focus event to the element, like: `element.onfocus=function(){/* .... */}`

Comment: I'm asking if there is a command to show the tooltip of validation without click the submit button.

Comment: Hum, I still didn't get what you want. :s A tooltip? Or do you want to submit the form without clicking in submit button?

Comment: When you submit the form and an input required is empty, I get a tooltip with the message "Please fill out this field". Can i get this tooltip witout click the submit?

Comment: You can't because this occurs in submit verifying function. You can just do something like this into a div.

Comment: Wait, it's possible. You can just check if the text box value is less than 1 and submit the form by the JS and you will get the message (but not sure that this message is in all browsers, by this it's good to do something different).